# DFS replication initial step problem

Tags: replication, dfs, dfs-r

I just setup DFS on my network and it's working fine, and now I'm trying to setup DFS-R on a test folder, but then at the end of the procedure (all went fine, selected my 2 folders, primary folder, replication topology and such) I get this error message (roughly translated from french) : Unable to define security on the replicated folder.  The shared administration folder doesn't exist.

I'm also wondering if there's any required security on the folders to replicate so that DFS-R can access it.  I was trying to add SYSTEM in the security, but it won't find it/allow me.  The folder has many many files and folders on the primary DFS pointer, but none on the 2nd, just created it with quite the same rights.

Note that the primary DFS pointer is on a 2008 server and the DFS service and the secondary DFS pointer are on a 2008r2.

Any help is very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: note that even with the SYSTEM user it doesn't change the situation (found it, it's now translated in french as Système instead of SYSTEM...) and I notice that my D: drive isn't accessible from my DFS-R "add replicated folders" wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable the admin share of my D: drive to stop getting the error.